# How can I verify if an email address is already use by a provider (Google or Facebook)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, web

In my web app I use login Firebase (**Google and Facebook**).

But I would like to prevent the user if their email address is already in use by **Google** or **Facebook**.

**Example:**

If my user would like connect with **Google**, their email address is **user@example.com** and after they would like to connect but with **Facebook** and his email address for **Facebook** is the same **(user@example.com)**.

How I can verify if the email address already exists?

Comment: check if the email already exists amongst your users

Answer (score 0):

Check out this links on firebase docs it should help you out with facebook login there are more examples on the site including that of google login

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#handling-account-exists-with-different-credential-errors

Comment: Thank you, but I already have the Facebook login and Google login in my code